# Why is the 'if' statement used in this code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int n){
    int sum = n;

    while(n>0){
        sum += n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    int check,i;
    int arr[10001];

    for(i=1;i<10001;i++){
        check = sum(i);
        if(check<10001) // this code 
            arr[check] = 1;

    }
    for(i=1;i<10001;i++){
        if(arr[i]!=1)
            printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why 'if(check<10001)' used

Comment: Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) info about how to ask, and edit your question

Comment: I don't know what the code is trying to do, but `arr` is defined as an array with 10001 elements. And without that `if` the next line would write past the last element, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: the whole code is broken. For any `i` that is no result of any `sum()` you access uninitialized array members in the second loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this last 10 outputs made without the `if(check<10001) arr[check] = 1;`:
`9990 9991 9993 9994 9995 9996 9997 9998 9999`

On the other hand, this one contains `if(check<10001) arr[check] = 1;`:
`9903 9914 9925 9927 9938 9949 9960 9971 9982 9993`

I assume that the second output is the one you wish to get.
As you see, the `sum()` function would not work as intended without `if(check<10001) arr[check] = 1;` as the "stopper", otherwise it will print every `check` calculated in the `i` loop.

Comment: thank you for answer.  sum(9999) = 9999 + 36 = exceeds 10001 but I write arr[10001] ,So write an if statement, Is this correct?

Comment: nope. if `check < 10001` becomes true and the check is omitted it invokes UB (writing beyond array limits). Anything could happen in that case